# ASP.NET Form validation - success event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I would like to subscribe to whatever event is fired when my ASP.NET form is validated successfully.

Here is the scenario: On the click of a button on a payment form, I want to show a message 'processing,' however I only want to show this button when the for is validated succesfully.

I am using native ASP.NET form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the built in validators expose any such events.  You could always use the `CustomValidator` and provide a `OnClientValidate` method that will combine the validation you're looking for as well as the UI changes you desire.

Answer (score 2):

In a round-about way, you can if you override the Page_ClientValidate method as in:

```
var fn = Page_ClientValidate;
Page_ClientValidate = function(..) {
    var result = fn(..);

    if (result == true) {
        //run code for success
    }
}
```

I don't know why this was demoted but this approach is great because it works from all validation scenarios for customization (from buttons, WebForms_DoPostBackWithOptions client method, etc.).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Call the following Javascript function whenever you want and pass the validation group name of your form to it..

```
function ValidateForm(ValidationGroupName)
{
    var validated=Page_ClientValidate(ValidationGroupName); 
    if(validated)
     {
        //do the logic here
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
       }
  }
```

Hope this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to be easy to do it your way but what you can do is the following:

```
<asp:Button onclientclick="if (Page_IsValid) return true; else {alert('Not Valid'); return false;}"/>
```

This will basically throw an error is validation is incorrect, otherwise it will continue.

Comment: doing this stopped my client side validation from working and a post back was made.  EDIT: Moved to a function and it didn't work either.